# Android keyboard is changing from numeric to alphabet

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, numeric

I did the following code in my program:

```
<RelativeLayout
....>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Header"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but whenever I tried it on my app, the app will first pop out the numeric keypad, and then a sec later, it will changed to alphabet keypad and the edittext is no longer on focus.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: It seems dependent on the device or maybe android version, can you provide more details?

Comment: my android manifest file - uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="14". Not sure that will affect it or not. I'm using Galaxy Nexus to test

Comment: Did you find the reason/solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somewhere in your layout or UI code something else is using `requestFocus`, perhaps another input field that is not of type number.

Comment: I checked my code, the only other input field i have in the activity is for the button. The button, when clicked, will call the datepicker dialog for user to enter the date.